# Problem with sharepoint 2013 start page after install

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, installation

After installation and configuration wizard had succeeded, it requires log in, and after log in this error is displayed:

> Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.
>   TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation
>   ID: 782e2e9c-7959-c03c-224c-afce18b0a1fb
>
> Date and Time: 7/11/2013 7:36:34 PM

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Use the *Correlation ID* to find the error in the ULS log which is found at **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS**. Reload the page to get a fresh error message and then open the latest modified log file.

Comment: In addition, you may need to update logging to verbose to really get some good detail. Update it in Central Admin > Monitoring > Configure diagnostic logging (or something close, if member serves me correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is old but in the future if you get a correlation ID you can simply open the management shell (SharePoint) and type the following:

merge-splogfile -correlation "your correlationID" -Path "C:\someDirectory\SomeFile.log

This will scan the entire farm regardless of server count and write any entries to SomeFile.log where you can open it with ULSViewer and see what's going on.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but I don`t know exactly what is the cause for this. I got rid of the issue by closing the browser and open it again.

It's not a caching issue since I tried to clear the cache many times.

Comment: PLease turn on the verbose logging and check the sharepoint logs with that correlation id 782e2e9c-7959-c03c-224c-afce18b0a1fb. Go to this link and download ULS viewer and share us your logs http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020